# Defining Components in React

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I am creating a react website in which many pages have a specific button that should look the same for all. Should this button be its own component? If so, how would I specify the onClick events to be different for each button if it is a component?

Comment: If you use it for submitting a form, you don't need to specify a `onClick` `event`, just set button `type='submit'` and use inside a `form` tag which you define `onSubmit`  
  For example `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}`>`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should be its own component.

Create it in a separate file so you can import them where you need to use.

The component should receive a onClick prop that you pass to the internal button tag.

See this example: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#composing-components

Answer (score 0):

```
export const Button = ({ label, onClick, disabled }) => {
    return (
        <button
           onClick={onClick}
           disabled={disabled}
        >
           {label}
        </button>   
    )
}
```

and then you can export this component inside any of the components you want, and pass in values like onClick and label to make it more dynamic

```
export const DemoFunction () => {
    const onClickHandler = () => {}

    return (
        <Button label="Click" onClick={onClickHandler} />
    )
}
```